# Delete a record in DataGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to delete a record in DataGridView but it is giving me this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@reg_id".

My reg_id is the primary key column in the table. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give default value to @reg_id in stored procedure where you declare this parameter.

```
like @reg_id = NULL or @reg_id = ' '
```

Comment: its giving me the same error...
and my query is "DELETE FROM insurance_table WHERE (reg_id = @reg_id=NULL)"

Comment: its giving me the same error... and my query is "DELETE FROM insurance_table WHERE (reg_id = @reg_id=NULL)"

Comment: you write query like "DELETE FROM insurance_table WHERE (reg_id=@reg_id)" But before this statement write where you declare this parameter there you write @reg_id = NULL. get it.