# cannot update in data grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

when i'm trying to update any data in the data Grid view then its giving me this error

"The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'date'. "

plz provide some solution to fix this error

Thanks,
Churchill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Datasource date to dateTime issue. Try to convert datatype of Date to Datetime. It would be helpful if you provide some more information like which Datatypes do you have.

Comment: but one more error is coming while i'm tryin to delete a record from data source grid view.."Must declare the scalar variable "@regid"."  my delete query "DELETE from tablename where reg_id=@regid"

Comment: Read this Thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386842/delete-a-record-in-datagridview

Comment: where can i be able to find the stored procedure

Comment: I guess you need to add the Parameter in your SQLCommand like: SQLcmd.Parameters.Add("@Aregid", sql_datatype, length). but im not sure.. See the example here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/876a5cc3-391d-42ea-a643-48ecf903f2c1